# getElementById or loading mehod issue undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to get the weather from a response array. I tried using the method directly however it returns weather is:undefined!

```
{text: 'Your current weather?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Your current weather is:' + (loadWeather()) + '!'}
```

I have tried using

```
{text: 'Your current weather?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input =>'Your current weather is:' + (document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML) + '!'}
```

It prints the result however the result in the answer and html code with the answer:
I just want the following response without the html tags

When the user is asked the question Your current weather? it should respond with this:

> Your current weather is:
>
> ### 8°C
>
> - Seattle, WA
>   Rain
> - 46°C
>
> !

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'},
  {text: 'What is your time?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Where I am located' + (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) + 'that is the day!'},
  {text: 'What language do you speak', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to me you speak: ' + language() + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (document.getElementById('address').innerHTML) + '!'},
  {text: 'You know you ip adress?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You ip adress is:' + (document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML) + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current weather?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input =>'Your current weather is:' + (document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML) + '!'}



 ];
 let ipinfoResponse;
 $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  ipinfoResponse = response;
}, "jsonp");

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 5000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').text(txt));
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});

function language () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLang
}

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");



// Docs at http://simpleweatherjs.com

/* Does your browser support geolocation? */
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  $('.js-geolocation').show();
} else {
  $('.js-geolocation').hide();
}

/* Where in the world are you? */
$('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude); //load weather using your lat/lng coordinates
  });
});

/*
* Test Locations
* Austin lat/long: 30.2676,-97.74298
* Austin WOEID: 2357536
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadWeather('Seattle',''); //@params location, woeid
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <img src="http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/138/377/fcc.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ffc.gif">
  <h1 class="text-center">Hello I am ZENYATTA!</h1>
  <br> <br>
  <div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>

<style>
.hide{
   display:none;
}
</style>
<div class="hide">
    <div id='ip'></div>
    <div id='address'></div>
    <div id="weather"></div>
    <button class="js-geolocation" style="display: none;">Use Your Location</button>
</div>
</div>




<!-- jquery for enter key press -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/s.js"> </script>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Can you be little more specific?

Comment: @Tumen_t The problem is that my result includes HTML tags in the weather result. JavaScript prints it out with tags and I want it with out tags. or if I use getElementsByClassName() it will not print it will result in a undefined print.

Comment: How about `$("#weather").innerHTML = html`?

Comment: @Tumen_t that won't work with a jQuery object

Comment: @Tumen_t it results in: Your current weather is:<h2><i class="icon-12"></i> 8&deg;C</h2><ul><li>Seattle, WA</li><li class="currently">Rain</li><li>46&deg;C</li></ul>! I don't want the tags to be printed!

Comment: You don't have to use Jquery. You can do `document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = html`.

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation of the problem

Comment: @Tumen_t Still the same result: Your current weather is:<h2><i class="icon-12"></i> 8&deg;C</h2><ul><li>Seattle, WA</li><li class="currently">Rain</li><li>46&deg;C</li></ul>! I dont want the tags to be with!

Comment: Then don't use tags when you create the html

Comment: @charlietfl but how am I supposed to keep the text in order and not messy?

Comment: You need to format the string like this `var html = "<h2><i class='icon-12'></i> 8&deg;C</h2><ul><li>Seattle, WA</li><li class='currently'>Rain</li><li>46&deg;C</li></ul>"`. Notice there is no double quotes used twice in the string.

Comment: Try this out https://jsfiddle.net/c9e12ozm/

Comment: to be honest you use html with classes that you can style the way you want it

Comment: @Tumen_t still results in tags printing out.

Comment: Have you tried the example in fiddle? As far as I can tell, it is showing the proper the HTML unless I misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish. https://jsfiddle.net/c9e12ozm/

Comment: @Tumen_t I am trying to get the weather from a certain API however it gives me the right answer but the answer prints it with tags!

Comment: So it prints with HTML tags because in your html string, you have "<h2><i class="icon-12"></i></h2>". It blows up because you have `"` used inside the string for `class="icon-12"`. It should be `"<h2><i class='icon-12'></i></h2>"`

Comment: Is this solved yet?  My first thought: you read getElementById before the DOM is loaded.  Don't use this data before window.onload or $(document).ready ...

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay No it's not solved I tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace your function `setOutput` (replace text by html)

( there is difference between `html()` and `text()` the first transform tag to dom element unlike text wich do not transoform your html text to dom node)

```
function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').text(txt));
}
```

By

```
function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').html(txt));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Notice a single quote is used for classes inside the html string.

```
function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = "<h2><i class='icon-"+weather.code+"'></i> "+weather.temp+"&deg;"+weather.units.temp+"</h2>";
      html += "<ul><li>"+weather.city+", "+weather.region+"</li>";
      html += "<li class='currently'>"+weather.currently+"</li>";
      html += "<li>"+weather.alt.temp+"&deg;C</li></ul>";

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's still the same still prints the html tags.

Comment: Change `setOutput function` to `output.html(txt);` and try again.